# How do I install an older version of Mercurial for TortoiseHG?

Tags: mercurial

I wish to install TortoiseHQ to use with Bitbuket in Ubuntu, but I cannot work out how. I am using the latest version of Ubuntu 12.04 at the time of this post.

I used these commands to install TortoiseHQ:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg
$ sudo apt-get install qct vim emacs kdiff3 kompare meld xxdiff tkcvs mgdiff
```

I am sure that this is how I had installed it last time, only a few weeks ago (setting up a mate's laptop now), but when I try to run TortoiseHQ workstation, I get this error:

```
** Mercurial version (2.2.1).  TortoiseHg version (2.3)
** Command: log
** CWD: /home/itisme
** Encoding: UTF-8
** Extensions loaded: 
** Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) [GCC 4.6.3]
** Qt-4.8.1 PyQt-4.9.1
This version of TortoiseHg requires Mercurial version 2.0.n to 2.1.n, but found 2.2.1
```

So I guess I need to install an older version of Mercurial, but I do not know how. Also, the context menus in the UI file browser are not showing up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Installing Mercurial from [ubuntuupdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/mercurial)

and then installing tortoiseHg using `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg` solved my problem.

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

[image: s3]

[image: s4]

Comment: I had to also download a new version of Mercurial-Common.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you installing TortoiseHg and Mercurial from PPAs if both are easily available from the Software Center?

If a given software requires an specific version to run, and this is not clearly described in the .deb package (which would prevent you from installing it when versions mismatch), I would seriously question the quality of those builds.

To avoid this kind of headaches is precisely what Software Center was made for.

That said, to install to a specific version of any package, do this:

```
apt-cache policy mercurial
```

Check `Version table` options. Choose one that fits Tortoise's requirement. then:

```
apt-get install mercurial=<version>
```

Comment: i am new to ubuntu i was just following the install instruction on the tortiseHQ website

Comment: @aJynks: And thus you had your first lesson on the do's and dont's of Ubuntu's Brave New World: this is not windows, you don't have to hunt for developers websites, your OS already conveniently provides more than 35.000 software for you in the Software Center, *including* TortoiseHg and Mercurial. And they are build and tested by people that knows the details of *your particular release*, something an upstream software developer rarely do.

Answer (score 0):

[Apt Pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html) is what you need. Plenty of documentation available on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

Installing TortoiseHg using `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg` solved my problem.